# массив и цикл с БД

Tags: php

такой вот вопрос, у меня есть таблица в БД , в ней 4 столбца.

```
ФИО , отряд, старая дата , новая дата.
```

у меня есть скрипт нахождения разницы между датами и вывода  в таком виде котором я хочу (вывожу посредством PDO) и вывода из через живую строку, то-есть я ввожу фамилию имя отчество и выводятся все записи с определённой фамилией и находилась разница по каждой отдельной записи по определённой группе

```
class DateIntervalEnhanced extends DateInterval {

    public function recalculate()
    {
        $from = new DateTime;
        $to = clone $from;
        $to = $to->add($this);
        $diff = $from->diff($to);
        foreach ($diff as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
        return $this;
    }

}
$datetime1 = date_create('02.10.2000');//здесь должна быть первая дата из БД
$datetime2 = date_create('02.10.2016');//здесь вторая дата из БД
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); //находит разницу

$a = $interval->format('%a'); //выдаёт разницу в днях

$interval1 = new DateIntervalEnhanced('P'.(int)$a.'D');
echo $interval1->recalculate()->format("%y г. %m мес. %d дн.");// переводит дни в формат год месяц день
```

две группы  с несколькими отрядами. одна группа вычисляется по  формуле выше, а другая группа ещё и умножается на 1.5. находится разница каждой записи и ещё это разница складывается.

я понимаю что мне нужен массив и цикл . проблема в том что я не понимаю как это связать вместе с выводом из БД ,кто может помочь мне с данной задачей?

Answer (score 1):

А может эти вычисления делать в самом запросе? Тогда просто циклом выводите и всё:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2000-10-02', '2016-10-02'), 
        ' г. ', 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2000-10-02', '2016-10-02') % 12, 
        ' мес. ', 
        FLOOR(
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2000-10-02', '2016-10-02') % 30.4375
        ), 
        ' дн.'
    ) AS `diff` 
FROM 
    DUAL;
-> 16 г. 0 мес. 0 дн.
```

Comment: в самом запросе не получится так как , это база карточек всех сотрудников, и получается что нужно будет по введение в поисковую строку ФИО сотрудника выводились все его карточки и сразу автоматически исходя из карточек находились все разницы дат(учитывая что человека могут перекидывать по отделам а там расчёт разный , в одном отделе считается обычно а в другом разница ещё и умножается на 1.5) и потом эти разницы ещё и складывались выдавая конечную суммарную разницу, если вы знаете как такое осуществить не могли бы вы мне рассказать как подобное осуществить